# how to use an insert statement inside a select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[login]
           ([Account_no]
           ,[Password])
     VALUES
           ((select Account_number from sign_up where ( INSERT into sign_up values(999,'Ani','M',20,'9030000018','A','a','b') ) )
           ,123)
GO
```

I want to insert a row in sign_up and then it should return Account_number which will be inserted into login table . 
But I am getting error near 'where '

Comment: That is not possible. Use seprate statements

Comment: (select Account_number from sign_up , INSERT into sign_up values(999,'Ami','M',20,'9038123518','A','a','b') ) )

Comment: How can I use both as different inside a insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the [OUTPUT Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to achieve this 
with one single query, instead.

```
INSERT into sign_up 
OUTPUT INSERTED.Account_number,'aPassword' into [dbo].[login] ([Account_no],[Password])
values(999,'Ani','M',20,'9030000018','A','a','b')
```